# multi file select form field

Tags: html

As far as I'm aware, plain html or javascript won't allow me to upload multiple files (images) in one field (correct me if I'm wrong).

Is this possible in html5 or any other way except flash?

I'd like to give my users the ability to select up to 5 images at once and upload them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`multiple`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/common-input-element-attributes.html#attr-input-multiple) attribute.

```
<input type="file" name="myFiles" multiple>
```

Comment: Awesome. How is this handled? `$_POST`?

Comment: No, $_FILES. Make sure you put multipart/form-data as your enctype in your form.

Comment: Thanks @Robinv.G. Does anyone know of a way to handle this in non html5 browsers?

Comment: Browsers which don't support that feature of HTML 5 will be able to upload a single file. If you want to upload multiple files in such a browser, you can use multiple file input elements.

Comment: `$_POST`? If you're using PHP then you'll probably have to do the usual silliness with `[]` on the end of the name.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<input size="40" type="file" name="_attachments[]" multiple="multiple"/>
```